# elasticsearch filter on nested array

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

```
lets say records have city field as an array of city names.
```

records ex:

```
  record 1:
    {
      cities : [
        {name: city1},
        {name : city2},
        {name : city3}
      ]
    }
    record 2:
    {
      cities : [
        {name: city2},
        {name : city3},
        {name : city4}
      ]
    }
    record 3:
    {
      cities : [
        {name: city3},
        {name : city4},
        {name : city5}
      ]
    }
```

requirement:
My filter criteria is to fetch the records matches with city1 or city2 or city3 but since the record 1 matches all 3 it should come first and record 2 matches 2 so it should come 2nd and record 3 matches only one so it should come last.

Comment: mapping: {
  "Cities": {
    "type": "nested",
    "dynamic": "true",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "city": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 32766,
            "normalizer": "lowerasciinormalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: record: {
  "Cities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "city": "Bangalore"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "city": "Hyderabad"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "city": "Delhi"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the `nested` data-type as you don't have the nested properties or complex object, its very simple and easy to achieve.

### Working example

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "cities": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "cities": [
        "tel-aviv", "bangalore", "sf"
    ]
}

{
    "cities": [
        "tel-aviv"
    ]
}

{
    "cities": [
        "sf"
    ]
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "cities": "tel-aviv"
                    }
                },
                {
                   "match": {
                        "cities": "bangalore"
                    }
                },
                 {
                   "match": {
                        "cities": "sf"
                    }
                }
            ] 
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result with proper expected result and score**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "cities",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.850198,
                "_source": {
                    "cities": [
                        "tel-aviv",
                        "bangalore",
                        "sf"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "cities",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.9983525,
                "_source": {
                    "cities": [
                        "tel-aviv"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "cities",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.6133945,
                "_source": {
                    "cities": [
                        "sf"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: The sample doc you took does not match my given doc. Cities : [ name : Bangalore, name : chennai , name : Hyderabad ] is my doc structure

Comment: @kuna can you provide the real doc in JSON format and provide your mapping, sample docs in proper JSON format, as I provided in my answer ?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja you are totally right, with new informations I can see that it's not a nested field issue

Comment: hi @OpsterElasticsearchNinja added comments in the question . please check

Comment: Hi , have you looked into this?

Comment: @kuna will look into in sometime

Comment: Ok. Waiting @opster :)

Comment: @kuna so I am looking at your edit and sample you provided in your question  is different than what is mentioned in question comment, could you please provide the proper JSON of your actual document?

Comment: I can't post my actual record. I posted my record sample. How to achieve my usecase is my query. Record sample is in comments @opster

Comment: any luck ?? @opster

Comment: @kuna you are unnecessary using nested data types which are costly and sorry but unless you explains your use case in detail its difficult to provide the optimised solution and as mentioned earlier pls provide the valid JSON, i don't need your actual records but sample records which matches your mapping and works so that its easy to work on your data, I already spent some time to give my initial answer without much info and still I don't feel I have all required info :(

Comment: Have you gone through the record mentioned in the comments. That is exactly my record structure. Please look into it and let me know @opster

Comment: hi @opster please have a look . updated with my actual record

Comment: hi @opster , please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63900682/need-elastic-search-query-for-the-below-required-scenario

Comment: hi @opster can you please answer this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63907775/get-relevant-data-on-elastic-search

Answer (score 0):

**Adding another answer with [nested bool queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html):**

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties":{
        "Cities": {
            "type": "nested",
            "dynamic": "true"
        }
    }}
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "Cities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "city": "Bangalore"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "city": "Hyderabad"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "city": "Delhi"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "Cities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "city": "Bangalore"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "city": "abc"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "city": "Def"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Cities",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "Cities.city": "Bangalore"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Cities",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "Cities.city": "Hyderabad"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "nested-63806067",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 3.297317,   <-- note this
                "_source": {
                    "Cities": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "city": "Bangalore"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "city": "Hyderabad"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "city": "Delhi"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "nested-63806067",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.6486585,   <-- note this
                "_source": {
                    "Cities": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "city": "Bangalore"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "city": "abc"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "city": "Def"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```