# get relevant data on elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-query, relevance

Need to apply search conditions on skills and years of experience on candidates

below are the conditions

1. Skills can be mandatory or non-mandatory
2. if we apply skills as mandatory then search result should include records which have skills and sorted
   accordingly
3. If we apply skills as non-mandatory search result should sort based on the most matched skills
4. Along with skills years of experience can also be applied like experience is greater than or less than some years, If years of experience applied then search result include records which match both skill name and years of experience condition and sorted with most matched records

Below are the details on mappings and query applied which is not working

//***myindexmapping***

```
{
                              "skills": {
                                "type": "nested",
                                "dynamic": "true",
                                "properties": {
                                  "id": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                  },
                                  "isHighlight": {
                                    "type": "boolean"
                                  },
                                  "skill": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                      "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 32766,
                                        "normalizer": "lowerasciinormalizer"
                                      }
                                    }
                                  },
                                  "yearsOfExp": {
                                    "type": "float"
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
```

**below is my index data**

```
{
                              "_index": "tenant1_candidate",
                              "_type": "docs",
                              "_id": "953",
                              "_score": 0.0074906712,
                              "_source": {
                                "record": {
                                  "skills": [
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Jr.Software Developer",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 2,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "AJAX",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Angular Developer",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "AngularJS",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Apache Subversion",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "API",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Bachelors Degree",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Back End",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Bootstrap",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Cascading Style Sheets",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "CRUD",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "CSS3",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Design Patterns",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Excellent analytical and logical programming skills",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Front End",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Git",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "HTML",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "HTML5",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "JavaScript",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "jQuery",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Jr. UI Developer",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "JSON",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Microsoft Access",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Microsoft SQL Server",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Microsoft Visual Studio",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "MySQL",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Object Oriented Analysis/Design",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Responsive Web Design",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "REST API",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "RESTful",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Test-Driven Development",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "TypeScript",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Version Control",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "Web Services",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "id": 0,
                                      "skill": "XML",
                                      "yearsOfExp": 1,
                                      "isHighlight": false
                                    }
                                  ]
                                },
                                "entityType": "Candidate",
                                "index": "tenant1_candidate",
                                "dbId": "953",
                                "id": "953"
                              }
                            }
```

**below is my search query**

```
 {
                              "from": "0",
                              "size": "30",
                              "track_scores": true,
                              "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                  "must": [
                                    {
                                      "term": {
                                        "entityType": "candidate"
                                      }
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "nested": {
                                        "path": "record.skills",
                                        "score_mode": "avg",
                                        "query": {
                                          "bool": {
                                            "should": [
                                              {
                                                "bool": {
                                                  "must": [
                                                    {
                                                      "match": {
                                                        "record.skills.skill.keyword": "XML"
                                                      }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                      "range": {
                                                        "record.skills.yearsOfExp": {
                                                          "gte": 0
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  ]
                                                }
                                              },
                                              {
                                                "bool": {
                                                  "must": [
                                                    {
                                                      "match": {
                                                        "record.skills.skill.keyword": "SQL"
                                                      }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                      "range": {
                                                        "record.skills.yearsOfExp": {
                                                          "gte": 0
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  ]
                                                }
                                              }
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
```

Example Data:

Candidate1 :
name: x,
skills: [ { name: sk1,  exp: 2 }, { name: sk2,  exp: 5 }, { name: sk3,  exp: 3 }]

Candidate2 :
name: y,
skills: [ { name: sk1,  exp: 1 }, { name: sk5,  exp: 4 }, { name: sk3,  exp: 1 }]

in search query skills can be mandatory or nonmandatory

1. If sk1 with 2 years of experience is applied as mandatory then only candidate1
   should come in results
2. If sk1 with 1 year of experience is applied mandatory then candidate1 and candidate2 should come in results and candidate1 should be the first record as it has more years of experience
3. If sk1 with 2 years of experience and sk5 with 4 years of experience as nonmandatory then both candidate1 and 2 should appear in the results however candidate2 should be the first record in the result as it matches mores skills

Comment: can yo please be more specific about your requirements. And it would be great if you can give sample of your expected search result

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja added example please let me know if you need any other details